# Set different markdown parser or different flavored markdown in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I set *kramdown* as markdown parser in the *_config.yml* and accept GFM as input. But I do not want to use GFM for some posts, how can I disable it?

Comment: No way to get around this except with a plugin.